# Curl development headers with SSL support for Phusion Passenger 3

Tags: centos, nginx, phusion-passenger, curl

I'm trying to install phusion passenger nginx module, but it fails

```
# passenger-install-nginx-module

* Curl development headers with SSL support... not found
```

...

```
yum install curl-devel

Setting up Install Process
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-9.el5.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package curl-devel-7.15.5-9.el5.i386 already installed and latest version
Nothing to do
```

What else needs to be done?
I use: CentOS 5.2, Phusion Passenger version 3.0.0, nginx/0.8.53

```
# gcc -v
Using built-in specs.
Target: x86_64-redhat-linux
Configured with: ../configure --prefix=/usr --mandir=/usr/share/man --infodir=/usr/share/info --enable-shared --enable-t
hreads=posix --enable-checking=release --with-system-zlib --enable-__cxa_atexit --disable-libunwind-exceptions --enable-
libgcj-multifile --enable-languages=c,c++,objc,obj-c++,java,fortran,ada --enable-java-awt=gtk --disable-dssi --enable-pl
ugin --with-java-home=/usr/lib/jvm/java-1.4.2-gcj-1.4.2.0/jre --with-cpu=generic --host=x86_64-redhat-linux
Thread model: posix
gcc version 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-48)
```

Comment: Does the `curl-devel` package install headers with SSL support? That would be one explanation of the error. Another might be that the package installed the libraries into a directory `passenger-install-nginx-module` isn't checking, e.g. `/usr/local/lib` rather than `/usr/lib`, but I don't rate that possibility very high.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`yum install libcurl-devel`

Answer (score 0):

Install these:

> yum install zlib-devel e2fsprogs-devel krb5-devel

Answer (score 0):

Refer to code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=554 for a discussion of this issue.

Particularly, Comment 4: code.google.com/p/phusion-passenger/issues/detail?id=554#c4

> The installer is hiding useful error messages. I was getting the same error on CentOS 5.3 with curl and curl-devel 7.15.5 installed.

I solved this problem by installing:

> zlib-devel
>   e2fsprogs-devel
>   krb5-devel

Answer (score 0):

It is actually `libcurl-dev` instead of `libcurl-devel`.

Comment: > It is actually libcurl-dev instead of libcurl-devel. is that for Debian (Debian-like) systems? The poster is asking about CentOS

Comment: At least on my system, CentOS 6, with the repos I have installed, it's libcurl-devel. Didn't fix my problem, but still... :)

Answer (score 0):

sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev

Comment: This is a Cent OS related question and Cent OS uses `yum` as default, not `apt-get`. Also, this question has accepted answer from 2010, so this isn't adding any value at all.