# Curl development headers with SSL support for Phusion Passenger 3

Tags: solaris, phusion-passenger

Hi When I run passenger-install-apache2-module I get:

Checking for required software...

- GNU C++ compiler... found at /opt/csw/gcc4/bin/g++
- Curl development headers with SSL support... not found

I followed this tutorial http://www.darkaslight.com/blog/entry/50-Installing-Phusion-Passenger-on-Solaris and I fixed all dependencies except Curl with SSL headers.

Comment: Linux version of the same problem: http://serverfault.com/questions/192975/curl-development-headers-with-ssl-support-for-phusion-passenger-3

Answer (score 1):

There is no need to do any of the tricks with CRLE as described in the link to darksaslight.com in the original question. In fact, I would try to remove any changes if you have done so. The build technique fixed the RUNPATH inside of the libraries so that it knows to look in the various /opt/csw/lib directories without any LD_LIBRARY_PATH or crle tweaks.

You will need the following OpenCSW packages in addition to the base ruby packages:

- ruby18_dev
- libidn_dev
- libcurl_dev
- rubygems
- gcc4g++
- ruby18_gcc4
- apache2_dev

The libidn_dev is non-obvious since the installer script "helpfully" hides the output of the test compile commmands that it runs. I found it by reviewing the output of truss and discovered that there was a linker error due to the missing library.

You will need to run the following commands either as root or under sudo. I prefixed all of my commands with sudo.

Install the rack and passenger gems:

```
/opt/csw/bin/gem install rack
/opt/csw/bin/gem install passenger
```

Then use this command to start compilation:

```
PATH=/opt/csw/bin:$PATH /opt/csw/bin/passenger-install-apache2-module --apxs2-path /opt/csw/apache2/sbin/apxs --auto
```

Once that gets going, you may see an error like this:

```
In file included from /usr/include/sys/types.h:18:0,
                 from ext/common/AccountsDatabase.cpp:26,
                 from ext/apache2/module_libpassenger_common/aggregate.cpp:5:
/opt/csw/lib/gcc/sparc-sun-solaris2.10/4.6.2/include-fixed/sys/feature_tests.h:341:2: error: #error "Compiler or options invalid for pre-UNIX 03 X/Open applications    and pre-2001 POSIX applications"
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ -Iext -Iext/common -Iext/libev -fPIC -...]
```

You can fix that by editing /opt/csw/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/compiler.rb and cleaning out the "-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500" from one of the flags statements. Like so:

```
                if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /solaris/                                                                                                                                                            
                    flags << '-pthreads'                                                                                                                                                             
                    #flags << '-D_XOPEN_SOURCE=500 -D_XPG4_2 -D__EXTENSIONS__ -D__SOLARIS__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
                    flags << '-D_XPG4_2 -D__EXTENSIONS__ -D__SOLARIS__ -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64'
                    flags << '-DBOOST_HAS_STDINT_H' unless RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /solaris2.9/                                                                                                              
                    flags << '-D__SOLARIS9__ -DBOOST__STDC_CONSTANT_MACROS_DEFINED' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /solaris2.9/
                    flags << '-mcpu=ultrasparc' if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /sparc/
```

This gets you to here:

```
In file included from ext/common/LoggingAgent/LoggingServer.h:48:0,
                 from ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp:43:
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedMessageServer.h: In member function 'void Passenger::EventedMessageClient::writeArrayMessage(const char*, ...)':
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedMessageServer.h:95:45: error: 'alloca' was not declared in this scope
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedMessageServer.h: In member function 'void Passenger::EventedMessageClient::writeArrayMessage(Passenger::StaticString*, unsigned int)':
ext/common/LoggingAgent/../EventedMessageServer.h:118:41: error: 'alloca' was not declared in this scope
rake aborted!
Command failed with status (1): [g++ ext/common/LoggingAgent/Main.cpp -o ag…]
```

To clear that up, edit /opt/csw/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/passenger-3.0.11/lib/phusion_passenger/platform_info/compiler.rb again, and put a line like:

```
flags << '-I/usr/include'
```

after "if RUBY_PLATFORM =~ /solaris/" . This is in the section as the above edit.

Also replace the line

```
flags << '-DHAS_ALLOCA_H' if has_alloca_h?
```

with

```
flags << '-DHAS_ALLOCA_H_' if has_alloca_h?
```

Note the additional underscore at the end of ALLOCA_H